# Is it illegal to post a software without permission?

Tags: software, india

I am making a software which would do gridcomputing (i.e combine many computers processes to speed up a Function/App/Computer) I would post it online like a virus and spread to computers. This software will not take any of data. Delete it. Use it. It will only use a little bit of internet and 10MB of RAM.

Comment: What do you mean you would "post it online like a virus?" Posting your own software is not a problem. If people decide to install it on many computers, then that is their choice, and it does not sound like what a virus does. A virus usually implies that you are installing software on computers without someone authorizing that action. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: Yes installing software without authorizing like a virus but not affecting the victim

Comment: I'm pretty sure you would get in trouble for this, think about it, what if it accidentally infects a protected government computer? Or why do I have to pay for your unauthorized use of my internet, electricity, and computer? Even if it isn't strictly illegal, it is certainly immoral.

Comment: In addition of @RonBeyer points, by introducing such a software you are (almost certainly) introducing new vulnerabilities in the system, even if you intend to use it in a completely "harmless" way.

Comment: @ComputerGuy:  You can't know that it won't affect the victim.  A virus that doesn't do anything to harm the system might cause problems with an update (one of the first Mac viruses was WDEF, and it caused problems with an OS later than the one it was developed on).  You'd have to be able to test on an incredible number of configurations of software and hardware, including ones that don't exist yet, to know that.  People have tried to make innocuous viruses before, and often failed to be harmless.

Comment: "installing software without authorizing like a virus but not affecting the victim": in the jurisdictions I'm familiar with, it's against the law to enter someone's house without their permission even if you don't steal anything or damage anything or cause any other harm.  You'd be better off getting people to be excited about your project and to volunteer to install your software.

Comment: @DavidThornley "People have tried to make innocuous viruses before, and often failed to be harmless": I haven't heard about that before.  Can you link to any examples?

Comment: What if a software was hidden in a website when the site open. The site will do all its work in the computer in JAVASCRIPT only.

Comment: Not communicate external malware apps and software. Just embedded in a website

Comment: @ComputerGuy If the user chooses to open the page and thus run the JavaScript program, then you are not installing anything or doing anything unauthorized.

Comment: @phoog the [Morris Worm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morris_worm) of 1988 is one notorious example. It was supposed to be completely benign, but it ended up taking down most of the Internet.  This was due to several rather simple programming errors, such as not bothering to detect when a host was already infected.

Comment: Design your program so that people install it voluntarily, and then you will likely have no problems. See SETI@home for an example. People install it voluntarily and it uses computing resources in the background to do tasks for research purposes. You aren't allowed to do this by infecting people's computers without permission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unauthorized use of a computer is illegal in most of the United States, and in many circumstances it is a [federal crime](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1030). Here's a [round-up of applicable laws](http://www.ncsl.org/research/telecommunications-and-information-technology/computer-hacking-and-unauthorized-access-laws.aspx) from the National Conference of State Legislatures.

Comment: What about India

Comment: I'm not familiar with Indian law, but I'd imagine they have similar laws. If your question is specifically about India, you should edit it to reflect that.

Comment: @ComputerGuy Look at http://www.wipo.int/wipolex/en/text.jsp?file_id=185999 Chapter IX. "If any person without permission of the owner or any other person who is incharge of a computer, ... accesses or secures access to such computer, computer system or computer network ... he shall be liable to pay damages by way of compensation not exceeding one crore rupees [~139 000 USD]." The document defines 'access' as "gaining entry into, instructing or communicating with the logical, arithmetical, or memory function resources of a computer."

Comment: Hey this same thing has been used by the USA to stop IRAN NUCLEAR bombs.(STUXNET) But the developers of this virus did not get into trouble as listed in these line.